Firefox Scrolling with NDOF Device
Would it be possible to get Firefox to work with an NDOF device like the 3DConnexion Spacemouse? For example, there is a program called Pureref for referencing images that works how I think Firefox should work with an NDOF device. The scrolling is perfectly smooth and enables vertical scrolling, horizontal scrolling, and zooming in and out. If anything it would be great to at least have high resolution vertical scrolling alone using an NDOF device in Firefox.

I have a SpacePilot Pro and it scrolls in Firefox on Windows 7. A bit too sensitive (fast) but controllable, probably adjustable as well. The icon in the system tray recognizes that it's being used in Firefox. Same results in Chrome. I've done nothing special to configure or add drivers.

Does your SpacePilot Pro scroll in increments in Firefox or does it scroll perfectly smoothly though? My SpaceMouse scrolls in Firefox, but by however many lines I have set in Windows. My SpaceMouse scrolls in Firefox like any other mouse wheel with each notch of a mouse wheel scrolling one step.

Are you asking it something is possible, or are you really asking HOW to get something working in a particular way? Please ask the question you need to ask. EDIT your post to focus on the actual question. Also, note the things you have tried so we know what not to suggest.
